# Timer having difficulty when decreasing in minutes

Tags: java, timer

Hi Im working on a timer program that counts down from 6:00 minutes. it works well (6:00, 5:59, 5:58... 5:01, 5:00, 4:59) but then after 4:59 it starts decreasing in minutes and not seconds (ex: 4:59, 3:59, 2:59) and I cant figure out why.

Heres the code:

```
//Drag Button
public class event implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    int count = 60;
    dragTimer.setText("6:00");
    TimeClass tc = new TimeClass(count);
    dragT = new Timer(1000, tc);
    dragT.start();
    }
}
public class TimeClass implements ActionListener {
    int counter = 60;
    int minute = 5;
    public TimeClass(int counter){
        this.counter = counter;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent tc){
        counter--;
        if(minute > 0){
            if(counter >= 0) {
                String countString = Integer.toString(counter);
                String minuteString = Integer.toString(minute);
                String numb = minuteString + ":" + countString;
                dragTimer.setText(numb);
            }
            if(counter < 10 || counter <= 1){
                String countString = Integer.toString(counter);
                String minuteString = Integer.toString(minute);
                String numb = minuteString + ":0" + countString;
                dragTimer.setText(numb);
            }
            if(counter < 0){
                int counter = 59;
                minute--;
                String countString = Integer.toString(counter);
                String minuteString = Integer.toString(minute);
                String numb = minuteString + ":" + countString;
                dragTimer.setText(numb);
            }
        }else{
            dragT.stop();
            dragTimer.setText("0:00");
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/). It is meant for these kinds of things and you don't have to keep track of your minutes and seconds individually.

Answer (score 3):

```
 if(counter < 0){
       int counter = 59;//change this to

counter = 59;
```

you are creating another counter variable, which scope will be in the if loop only

instead you should reset previously(already) declared variable

the next time your loop is getting executed, the counter value will not be the one you expected by assigning it to 59